# Como enviar dados via formulário para arquivo php e retornar o resultado em um campo html

Tags: php, javascript, html

Queria enviar os dados via formulário, que seria usado na minha classe php, e com o javascript capturar esse resultado e jogar no meu campo em html, com o on click do js. Mas não estou conseguindo com "action", porque ele faz a requisição para outra página, no caso meu arquivo .php. E eu não recebo o retorno no meu arquivo html. Qual a melhor forma de resolver isso?

Tenho o seguinte formulário:

```
<form  class="form" method="GET">
     CEP: <input type="text" name="cep" placeholder="Insira o cep" required/>
     <input class="submit" type="submit" value="Buscar"/>
</form>
```

E um campo para receber os dados em php:

```
<article class="data">
     <!--Dados PHP via JS-->
</article>
```

No arquivo .js:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
     $(document).on('click', '.submit', function(){
          $.post('testephp.php', function(retorna){
          $(".data").html(retorna);
          });
     });
});
```

Classe php:

```
Class Controller{
    public $cep;

    public function ConsultaViaCEP(){
        $cep = Controller::setFormCEP();
        $cep = preg_replace("/[^0-9]/", "", $cep);
        $url = file_get_contents("http://viacep.com.br/ws/$cep/json/");
        $json = json_decode($url, true);
        return $json;
    }
    [...getters and setters]

    echo Controller::getCEP()."<br>";
    echo Controller::getLogradouro()."<br>";
    echo Controller::getComplemento()."<br>";
    echo Controller::getBairro()."<br>";
    echo Controller::getLocalidade()."<br>";
    echo Controller::getUF()."<br>";
}
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 0):

Se a questão for como entendi, você pode usar `preventDefault` para impedir que a página seja submetida e rode apenas no JS.

```
$(document).on('click', '.submit', function( e ){
     e.preventDefault();

     $.post('testephp.php', function(retorna){
          $(".data").html(retorna);
     });
});
```

Comment: o action do formulário, manda os dados do formulário html, enviando e redirecionando para o arquivo php, porém, eu queria receber os dados do formulário html, que o php processasse esses dados e enviasse o resultado para o campo em html destinado para isso, ou seja a parte em "amarelo"

Comment: Talvez recebendo os dados do formulário html pelo js e o próprio javascript mandasse para o meu arquivo php, resolvesse esse problema, já que ele não tem carregamento de página. Mas tem vários problemas ao fazer isso, primeiro sei não dizer se seria o correto e também, não sei como isto seria feito